Does anyone know of a molecule or material that has a strong and sharp absorption peak at 2 microns?
My lab studies quantum imaging, and we are having some (surprising) difficulty finding an interesting (doesn't have to be) molecule or material that has a sharp absorption peak at 2 microns. If anyone happens to know of any, that would be very helpful and very much appreciated!
Edit: a solid state phase of matter is preferable (we'd like to stay away from vacuum chambers, etcetera, if possible) but we are willing to build such an apparatus if necessary, so really any phase of matter would be very helpful.

the internet says the Satanic Gas (CO2) has a 2 micron peak. If not, take another molecule and doppler shift it to 2.

From my understanding, it is close, but not sharply peaked at 2 microns. Thanks anyway!

Water has a strong absorption peak at 1.94 microns.
You don't give us a lot of information e.g. what form do you need your sample in? Gas? Liquid? Solid?
There is quite a lot of work published on lasers that emit around 2 microns. It would be worth you checking that as the systems that emit at 2 microns will also absorb at 2 microns.

Absorption spectra does not necessarily matches emission spectra.

@AgniusVasiliauskas true but it's still an avenue worth pursuing.

Thanks! I've had a look at such systems, but typically they are some heterostructures or other not-so-easy to acquire materials (we would like to stay away from fabrication if possible).
I suppose gases will have sharper peaks (on average). I suppose ideally we are looking for a solid state material that's easily added to the experimental setup, but really anything will do. It appears there's a kind of universal anomolous 2 micron transmission. Never have I had so much trouble finding materials with absorption at some wavelength within the UV to deep IR range.
